# Swift way to C-style for loop that alters initial variable?

Tags: swift, loops, for-loop

In many languages a for loop is able to alter `i` like the below. This for loop will double i each loop around.

```
for(int i = 0; i < total; i = i + i){}
```

Swift has `for var i in stride(from: 0, to: total, by: N)`

and `for i in 0..<total`

but neither allows us to alter `i` like the C style for loop above.

Is there a Swifty way to do this? 
The goal is to change the pace each loop around instead of in a constant way like the N in stride.

Comment: "Don't do that." Now I know that sounds dismissive, but in a surprisingly high proportion of the time, you can write your code in a way that doesn't mutate the indices. Even in languages that have mutable indices like C, you would want to avoid it. The `for` loop line is very semantically important, because it lays out exactly how the entire block of code below it will apply. If the indices are allowed to be mutated mid-iteration, then the inferences made from reading the `for` loop become invalid, forcing you to always need to read the full loop body to understand how the iteration will work

Comment: If you give us more information about what your loop body looks like, we can help you rewrite it. As a matter of last resort, you can use a `while` loop instead. If you call the C-style for loop parts `for (A; B; C) { Body }`, you can always replace whose in Swift with `A; while (B) { Body; C }`

Comment: Related: https://www.reddit.com/r/swift/comments/en4ocd/rip_c_style_for_statements/fdz1rs1?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x

Comment: This came up while looking at a "bottom-up" example of merge sort written in Java and I was converting it to Swift. But the question is really more general as I was curious if a similar tool exists. The code I'm reading is grouping twice as many times to merge: for(int i = 0; i < N; i = i + i){ for(int low = 0; low < N-i; low += i + i){ merge(array, low, low+i-1, Math.min(low+i+i-1, N-1)) } }

Comment: Oh I didn't see that `i = i + i` part of your `for` loop. Not kidding! I thought it was `i = i + 1`. This is why we have `i *= 2` ;)

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the `sequence` global function. The equivalent of your

```
for(int i = 0; i < total; i = i + i)
```

(I assume you meant 1, not 0, since otherwise you'd just get 0 forever, eh?) is:

```
let total = 100 // let's say
let seq = sequence(first:1) {$0 >= 100 ? nil : $0 + $0}
for i in seq {
    print(i)
}
```

Output:

```
1
2
4
8
16
32
64
128
```

Comment: NIce benefit of this: you can pass around this sequence just like any other value, with the full toolbox of the `Sequence` interface. You can't do that with a C style loop, without materializing it out into memory.

Comment: Also, I think it's better to separate iteration and boundary conditions, just my $0.02: `sequence(first: 1) { $0 * $0 }.prefix(while: { $0 < 100 })`